# How do I add a number to another number in a list when the value in the list is greater than 0?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add a number to each value in a list when the value is greater than 0 unless the 0 value is at the index location.

I've been able to get the index value to increase but not the other values that are greater than 0.

Example:

```
LstA = [1,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0]    
lstA[index] += 2   
new_list = [3,0,5,0,0,4,2,0,0,0]
```

where lstA[index] above = 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
LstA = [1,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0] 
index = 6

new_list = [i+2 if i >0 else i for i in LstA]
new_list[index] += 2
# [3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks a lot!